# Does Spring automatically Autowire constructor args in java bean definitions?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have the following bean definitions

```
@Bean
public Beehive beehive(ArrayList<Bee> bees) {
    return new Beehive(bees);
}

@Bean
public ArrayList<Bee> bees() {
    return new ArrayList<Bee>();
}
```

Would the `bees` in the `beehive` bean method be Autowired in?

I am asking because I have an application that is behaving like this without using the `@Autowired` annotation, and want be make sure I understand what's going on.

Comment: I believe it is. A good way to make that more explicit if they're in the same class is to simply use `return new Beehive(bees());`. The arg can then be removed from the `beehive` bean method.

Comment: You should use `List` rather than `ArrayList` in the method signatures.

Comment: @EngineerDollery but what if I want to ensure that only `ArrayList` is used to keep bees?

Comment: This is almost never the case. Also, `bees` would not usually be a bean -- business objects are rarely beans. Beans are usually service constructs. Bees is something you'd like to be able to create on the fly (no pun intended), in response to some event, so it shouldn't be a bean. This also means that you probably wouldn't want to inject it into the Beehive service, but rather pass it in via some action method so that it can be processed statelessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Spring automatically Autowire constructor args in java bean definitions?

Yes, it does. You can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-bean-annotation) from the Spring doc which I have added below (emphasis mine).

> **A @Bean annotated method can have an arbitrary number of parameters
>   describing the dependencies required to build that bean**. For instance
>   if our `TransferService` requires an `AccountRepository` we can
>   materialize that dependency via a method parameter:
>
> ```
> @Configuration 
> public class AppConfig {
>     @Bean
>     public TransferService transferService(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
>         return new TransferServiceImpl(accountRepository);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **The resolution mechanism is pretty much identical to constructor-based
>   dependency injection**.